# Move Large Data Volume objects to Big Objects

Tags: managed-package, isv, big-object, largedatavolumes, ldv

I have built an [Open-Source tool that collects App Errors in Managed Packages](https://github.com/rsoesemann/lma-app-cockpit) and creates Custom Object records for each of them in a Salesforce org. This app can produce thousands of records per day. The more apps and subscribers you have the more.

Users of this app soon run into a general Salesforce issue. Expensive record storage. Each record counts 2 Kbyte and getting more is expensive.

So my question is about how to best cope with such situations. In general, I know what options I have.

1. Delete outdated records using Scheduled Jobs
2. Merging similar records using Duplicate Matching
3. Moving older `Custom Objects` records to `Big Objects` records

**What worked for you, what approach, and which steps do you recommend?**

- As this app is also a package this must also be an approach that works in packages.
- Are Big Objects a good option?
- Which restrictions and additional costs or limits should I take care of?